# Allow user modify nice without giving root permisions

Tags: ubuntu, process-priority

Is there any way to allow user modify process niceness without giving root permisions?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Do using `sudo nice` counts as _giving root permissions_?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/564375/allow-users-to-set-higher-lower-nice-levels

Answer (score 2):

Since allowing `sudo nice` is pretty much the same as granting root permissions, I would not consider doing that.

I see two possible solutions:

1/ Allow the full command via sudo and pin it's parameters, like:

```
%nicegroup ALL=/bin/nice --20 /bin/whatever
```

But that works only if it is always the same program that needs nice'ing.

2/ Allow only `renice` via sudo like this:

```
%nicegroup ALL=/bin/renice
```

The users then need to start their program like always and afterwards manually renice it via `sudo /bin/renice 20 -p $PID`.
That is manual effort, but it can be scripted to be automated.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. `nice` is one of those commands that will run the process given in its own context  - that is, if you allow `sudo nice`, any commands passed to `nice` will be executed as root. It may be possible to use `/etc/limits.conf` and use nice limits that way and run the script you want to be higher/lower priority, but it doesn't help with `renice`.